# global values not updating when changed in config/initializers/constants.rb in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, constants, global, config, initializer

I am working on a rails project and I am trying to update some of the global arrays used for selection fields in the application. I went into the constants.rb file where all the array definitions reside. I modified the values to be what I wanted. But when I go to the application to view the changes, they don't seem to be updated.

I looked around and from what I can tell the only way for these values to be updated is to restart the server. But I only have access to the server through SSH. Is this true? or is there another way to refresh these values? I tried refreshing the browser cache but that didn't make a difference. Any insight would be appreciated, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to restart the server for these changes to take affect.  Depending on how things are setup "server" might mean different things.  It might be Apache, nginx, unicorn, thin, or something else.

It may also eventually "restart" itself if it has a timeout functionality like Passenger does.

Random thought... is there any source code control and deployment process in place?  I don't see many folks changing files directly on the server these days... I mention it in case there is since the next time it gets deployed your changes will be lost.

Comment: I got hired to finish a project since the previous group that worked on it hacked it to pieces. So much broken functionality its a joke. So no they didn't put it up on a repo (even though most of the other projects here are up on GitHub). We debated pushing it up to GitHub but they opted against it since they just wanted me to finish fixing it instead... I think they are hosting it through rackspace, but when they rebooted the server now the dev site is completely down... And when you put in the direct ip address to the server in the address bar it just says Nginx.